# How to open a panel with Javascript?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have this code:

```
<?xul-overlay href="chrome://myextention/popup.xul"?>

<toolbarbutton id="button" type="menu">
    <panel id="popup" />
</toolbarbutton>
```

When I click the `button` it opens the `popup` panel. Now I want to open the same panel when I click an element in another window. I'm getting the current browser with `navigator:browser`, finding the panel ( e.g. `panel.state` works ) and trying to open it but it doesn't work.

I've tried `openPopup`, `open = true` and `openPopupAtScreen` - none of this works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

openPopup is definitely the correct way to open the panel.

I believe the problem is that you've made the panel child of the toolbarbutton.

I would suggest making the panel a separate item in the XUL (a child of mainPopupSet).

Then use openPopup in both cases.

Comment: I moved the panel outside the button and added `click` event on the button: `$panel.openPopup()`. It works.
After that I added `click` event on an element in another window (`window.open`) and again, even though I get the panel element, it ignores `openPopup`.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post some more code? I'm not sure what you mean by "ignores openPopup"

If a popup is already open and you call openPopup, it won't be moved to the new location. You would have to hide and reopen.